# setNext() method in node class not working

Tags: c++, stack, queue, nodes, abstraction

I have a program that creates a queue of stacks and each stack has several single-link nodes that have objects of a "function" class I created. However, any time I try to call my enqueue code it creates a segfault.

The first time the error comes up, it's a call that tracks like this:

`Executive.cpp : q.enqueue(*thisStack);
myQueue.cpp [enqueue method] : m_back->setNext(newNode);
SLNode.h [setNext method]: setNext(SLNode<T>* nextSLNode) {next = nextSLNode;}`

I'm not sure what creates the segment fault. I ran a test and the new node that is created in enqueue contains all the data it should, so I know it isn't empty. For some reason everything appears to work correctly, until it reaches the setNext method and I can't figure out why it won't run the code.

SINGLY-LINKED NODES

```
#ifndef SLNODE_H
#define SLNODE_H

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class SLNode // A node in a singly linked list
{
private:
    T item;
    SLNode<T>* next; // we can only go "forward" along our chain
public:
    SLNode(T anItem) : item(anItem), next(nullptr) {}
    SLNode(T anItem, SLNode<T>* nextSLNode) : item(anItem),                    
        next(nextSLNode) {}
    T getItem() const { return item; }
    SLNode<T>* getNext() const { return next; }
    void setItem(T newItem) { item = newItem; }
    void setNext(SLNode<T>* nextSLNode) { next = nextSLNode; }
};

#endif
```

QUEUE HEADER

```
#ifndef MYQUEUE_H
#define MYQUEUE_H

#include "SLNode.h"
#include "QueueInterface.h"
#include "myQueue.h"
#include "function.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename ItemType>
class myQueue: public QueueInterface<ItemType>
{
public:
    myQueue();

    bool isQueueFull(SLNode<ItemType>* node);

    bool isEmpty() const;
    void enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry); // throw     (PrecondViolatedExcep) = 0;
    void dequeue (); // throw (PrecondViolatedExcep) = 0;
    ItemType peekFront() const; // throw (PrecondViolatedExcep) = 0;

private:
    SLNode<ItemType>* m_front;
    SLNode<ItemType>* m_back;

};

#include "myQueue.cpp"
#endif // MYQUEUE_H
```

ENQUEUE METHOD

```
template<typename ItemType>
void myQueue<ItemType>::enqueue (const ItemType& newEntry)
{
    //create new node of ItemType and fill with given entry
    SLNode<ItemType>* newNode = new SLNode<ItemType>(newEntry);
    std::cout << "new queue node created\n";

    /*ItemType tester = m_back->getItem();
    std::cout << "new node functions properly\n";
    std::cout << tester.getProcessName() << std::endl;*/

    if(isQueueFull(newNode) == true)
    { throw PrecondViolatedExcep("Queue/Memory full."); }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "inside else statement\n";
        //point back to new node
        m_back->setNext(newNode);
        std::cout << "last node pointing to new node\n";
        //set back to new node
        m_back = newNode;
        std::cout << "new node is now back\n";
    }

}
```

THE RUN

```
:~/EECS268/Lab_05$ ./Lab_05 example.txt
start begun 
load : 'y' ,0
process added to stack.
read : 'n' ,0
process added to stack.
play : 'n' ,0
process added to stack.
0 : 'S' ,0
new queue node created
inside else statement
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: I see 2 issues in your enqueue method. Step through that line-by line either mentally or with a debugger and think through what it is actually doing.  Also think about what might be different between the first and second time it is called.

Comment: If this is a queue, why the stack tag?

Comment: @AviBerger I have a queue full of stacks and at the beginning of writing I was still trying to grasp what the issue was. I didn't know if the issue was actually where the error seemed to think it was.

Comment: also DUH!!!! I spent so long on this and I just forgot the empty queue exception, I'm so dumb. Thank you so much. You're an actual angel. @AviBerger

Comment: OK, the empty queue case was one of the issues. If this is  code for a queue rather than a stack, I think you will find one more problem here.